# Issue concerning understanding of independence in probabilities

Tags: probability

I've been going back and forth over the idea of independence in probabilities and it doesn't make much sense to me.

I have this example that I took from the book *All of Statistics* by Wasserman:

> In tossing a fair die, let A = {2, 4, 6} and let B = {1, 2, 3, 4}. Then A $\cap$ B = {2, 4}; P(AB) = 2/6 = P(A)P(B) = (1/2) * (2/3) and so A and B are independent.

When two events are independent, it means that the occurrence of one has no impact on the other event. But if you were to toss a fair die for A, and then do another toss for B, wouldn't your two tosses be independent no matter what? I struggle to grasp why if I simply add a 5 to event B, then the two events are now not independent.

Comment: I think the point is that we are looking at the same toss of a dice, not two different ones. So, given that the result is in $A$ (and so it can be $2$,$4$ or $6$) the probability it is in $B$ is the same as if we had no information on the toss. (this definition is $\mathbb{P}(B)=\mathbb{P}(B|A)$, but $\mathbb{P}(B|A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$ and so it is equivalent to yours)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm still confused as to the second part of question. If I simply add an event C to this story that is the same as B but with a 5 added to its set, then the events are not independent anymore as P(A$\cap$C) = 2/6 $\neq$ P(A)P(C) = (1/2) * (5/6)

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Intuitively, how does that make sense? how does now A have an impact on C when it didn't have any on B? (thanks for your answers again!)

Comment: Just forget about B for the moment! We are only considering A and C. Knowing the number is even reduces the probability of being in C to 2/3 , while having no information gives 5/6 as result! Thus, having the information that the number is in A has an impact on the probability of it being in C.